# What is the inclination (grade) of the trail?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, slope

In the problem:

A straight traail with a uniform inclination leads from a hotel, elevation $5000$ feet, to take a lake in a valley, elevation $600$ feet. The Length of the traill is $4100$ feet. What is the inclination (grade) of the trail?

I solved it like this:
$$grade = \frac{rise}{run}$$

$$\frac{5000-600}{4100}$$

$$\frac{4400}{4100}$$

$$\text{grade}=\frac{44}{41} \  \text{or} \   1.07317...$$

In other reference, it says that it's needed to be in percent, but what I know is that it's okay to be in just decimal or fraction. Is what I know right?

How do you visualize this? I can't think of how it can be drawn like a right triangle.

Comment: A 45 deg slope (grade) is 1 which is 100%. Simply multiply your slope (grade) by 100%.

Comment: yes that's right. but is that necessary? I mean if this question is in a quiz, the must be 107% and 1.07 is not accepted?

Comment: Either answer is correct, it would be very harsh for a grader to not accept either especially if it wasn't specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct.  The way you can describe the grade is either as a decimal ($1.07$), as a  fraction (in your case, $1$ in $0.93$), or a percentage ($107\%$). It depends on what the quiz is asking (e.g. "Give your answer as a percentage grade").

Comment: The situation you are describing here is impossible.  If you draw a line from the lodge  to a point directly under the lodge at the height of the lake, you get one leg of a triangle, of length 5000- 600= 4400 ft.  But the length of the trail is at least the length of the hypotenuse of that right triangle so must be **greater** than 4400- it cannot be 4100 feet.

Comment: The "run" of a slope is that horizontal distance, the other leg of the right triangle, NOT  the hypotenuse.

Comment: You are correct, user247327...I've removed that statement from my original post.